# Regular expression matches special character

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-Minute-Regex-Tutorial).

When I was trying to test my regular expression (The method dump is from linqpad to display it on the console):

```
Regex.Match("a^7lowah", @"\ba\w*\b").Success.Dump();
```

It should match a word that starts with an "a" and has x amount of alphanumeric characters to the end of the word.

But unfortunately the regex above matches.

My understanding of the regex:

- "\b" (begin of the word)
- "a" (just the letter a)
- "\w" (alphanumeric character)
- "*" (repeat previous term)
- "\b" (end of the word)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's really weird, there is nothing wrong with your regexp and it shouldn't match.

Comment: You should specify why you don't want this match to be successful. Is it because the leading `a` is followed by a `^` rather than a space? Is it because you want the whole of the input to have to match the output? Is it because the `a` is followed by 0, rather than 1 or more, other letters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the regex will match.

```
Pattern: \ba\w*\b
String: a^7lowah
```

The `*` means "zero or more".

So this will be the match:

[image]

As you can see, no word characters are matched, but because you're quantifying "zero or more", it does not matter - our pointer skips over that part of the construct, and are already possible in asserting a word boundary.

You might want to change `*` to `+` instead.

**Read also:**

- [The Stack Overflow regex reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618/3622940)

Comment: +1, you were not only faster, but your answer describes the OP's problem better.

Comment: Thanks, changing the "*" to "+" works! It was indeed matching the a as a word. Because it thinks "^" is the end of the word.

Answer (score 1):

It matches only the `a` of your string.

Since `a` is a word character and `^` is not a word character, the empty string between them defines the word boundary. (for `\b`)

In your case the `a` is matched because it is followed directly by the word boundary as mentioned above. The reason is that the `*` matches zero or more characters of the preceding token.

See [here](http://regexr.com/39jv3).

Depending if your `x` should be 1 or more tokens instead of 0 or more tokens, you need to change to `\ba\w+\b`.

Comment: Since `a` is a word character and `^` is not a word character, the empty string between them defines the word boundary.

Comment: @nhahtdh may I edit this into the answer? Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in your Regexp, it's in your interpretation of success. The regexp matches the "a" only, but that is still a match and Success will be true.

Comment: I just noticed this, i didn't know it would count a special character (in this case "^" as an end of a word. So a would be matched. When i used: ^ in het begin and $ at the end of the regex then it works just fine.